# textbox visibility/collapsed in silverlight mvvm

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

I Silverlight5 with mvvm pattern i have one doubt.
  In xaml i have used one textblock and i bind some id in it.
  If the textblock content value is 1 or 2 means
  yet another textbox is visible or else that is collapsed.. how to acheive that..

my code:

```
 <TextBlock Name="textBlock1" Text="{Binding id}" Loaded="textBlock1_Loaded" Visibility="Collapsed" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding name,Mode=TwoWay}"  x:Name="t1" Visibility="{Binding IsVisible,Converter={StaticResource visibilityconverter}}" />
```

in view model i had created the property for id and raised the event and bind the value to textblock.

to convert the value to visible i have a visibilityconverter class in one separate folder named "Converters"

```
public class visibilityconverter:IValueConverter
    {

       public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
                                       object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (id==1 && id==2)
            {
                return Visibility.Visible;
            }
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
                                    object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

    }
```

in the above visibleconverter class how i cna get the id value from viewmodel and check it..
 If i got the value from viewmodel to visibilityconverter means i will proceed further.

tell me if u can..!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi i have found the solution..

```
 In xaml give the following:

<TextBox Text="{Binding name,Mode=TwoWay}"  x:Name="t1" Visibility="{Binding id,Converter={StaticResource visibilityconverter}}" />
```

In visibilityConverter class:

public class visibilityconverter:IValueConverter
{

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
                               object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    string v = value.ToString();
    if (v =="1" ||  v=="2")
    {
        return Visibility.Visible;
    }
    return Visibility.Collapsed;
}

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
                            object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

}

Problem Solved... !